# Avoid a for() loop and if in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, netcdf, netcdf4

I have a question about avoiding a for() loop in R. I have looked at all the posts on this topic and nothing answers my question. So here goes, I have two data files one file with latitude and longitude for 60 cities (see this [CSV file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x27s2o4egz6lb8f/60cities-lat-lon.csv?dl=0)) and one 2D array file with multiple variables (see this [netCDF file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/te2mwty3p0ujg9l/England_aggr_GPW4_2000_0000.nc?dl=0)). I have a small calculation that'll convert each lat-lon to a row-col. After the row-col calculation those numbers are used to edit a variable in a netCDF file. In the below REVISED code I am using a for() loop. Is there a way to avoid the for() loop and the if() condition?

```
#install.packages("ncdf4", dependencies = T) 
library(ncdf4)

episim <- nc_open("England_aggr_GPW4_2000_0000.nc", write = TRUE)

currInhabitable <- t(ncvar_get(episim, episim$var[[4]]))
S <- t(ncvar_get(episim, episim$var[[1]]))
I <- matrix(0, 64, 44, byrow = T)

outbreak <- read.csv("60cities-lat-lon.csv", header = T)

for (ff in 1:dim(outbreak)[1])
{
  row <- abs(round((outbreak[ff,2] - 55.25833)/0.08333333))
  col <- abs(round((outbreak[ff,3] + 5.416667)/0.1666667))

  newInf <- outbreak[ff,4]

  #print(paste("Is the current cell inhabitable or not?", currInhabitable[row, col]))

  if (currInhabitable[row, col] == 1 & S[row, col] > newInf)
  {
    S[row,col] <- S[row,col] - newInf
    I[row,col] <- I[row,col] + newInf
  }
  print(c(row, col, S[row,col], I[row,col]))
}

t = 1
print(paste("Epidemic state saved to a netCDF file on day", t))

episimNew <- nc_create(paste("England_aggr_GPW4_2000_000", t, ".nc", collapse="", sep=""), episim$var)

ncvar_put(episimNew, episimNew$var[[1]], t(S))
ncvar_put(episimNew, episimNew$var[[2]], t(I))

nc_close(episimNew)
nc_close(episim)
```

Comment: look at `sapply` link here : https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/r-tutorial-apply-family

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr` you can do it in one line:

```
library(dplyr)

outbreak %>% mutate(row = abs(round((.[,2] - 55.25833)/0.08333333)), col = abs(round((.[,3] + 5.416667)/0.1666667)))
```

Comment: What do you try to do? If you are trying to work with spatial data, maybe what you are doing isn't the right way

Comment: Hi @aldo_tapia , yes I am using spatial data but I am dealing with matrices. I am trying for a way to avoid for() loops. I have never been able to understand and use lapply or sapply. Any suggestions from you? greatly appreciate your feedback or solving this. Sincerely

Answer (score 0):

You can update the column of your csv file by using these code:

```
outbreak$lat = abs(round((outbreak$lat- 55.25833)/0.08333333))
outbreak$lon = abs(round((outbreak$lon + 5.416667)/0.1666667))
```